# How to make results list names instead of emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like the following Google Script to display the members of a group email by name instead of by email.

```
function listGroupMembers() {
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("example@googlegroups.com");
    console.log(group.getEmail() + ':');
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    console.log(user.getEmail());
      }
    }
```

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
function listGroupMembers() {
     var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("example@googlegroups.com");
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
     console.log(user.getUsers());
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("example@googlegroups.com");
  var users = group.getUsers();
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    // call user.getEmail(), instead of user.getUsers();
    console.log(user.getEmail());
  }
}
```

Example code here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group

Comment: When I call user.getEmail it lists emails, but I want the names and not the emails.

Comment: This is the definition for User: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html It doesn't list other properties that can be accessed other than email, you can also console.log `user` to see what properties/methods are available